# Two floats data-type for mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, datatable, mysql-workbench, sqldatatypes

I have a question please. I have this data and I want to insert in my SQL using python. I have created a table with 4 columns. for ID, title, description and geolocation respectively. My question is, for id (int), for title (varchar), for description (varchar). However, for geolocation I am confused. I have Loc and Lat together. I was told not to use varchar. So I used decimal, float and it did not work. The only hint given to me is I have 2 floats and that is how the data-type should be. What can I do?

```
('3', "Τάφρος Ντ'Αβίλα (D'Avila)", '-1', '35.169194,33.363113')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use a `SPATIAL` index to make certain searches more efficient, then see the `POINT` datatype.

Otherwise, consider using two `FLOATs`.  That gives a resolution of 1.7 meters (5.6 feet).

If you will have a billion data points, the size of the datatype used matters; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices